# AppDomainManager with an XBAP

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain, xbap

I'm trying to dynamically load an application domain manager within an XBAP.  When running the application, the application domain manager is never hit and VS tells me that symbols are not loaded for my domain assembly.  If I load this assembly in a regular WPF application, the break point gets hit.

In my app.config I have:

```
<runtime>
    <appDomainManagerType value="MyDomain.MyDomainManager"/>
    <appDomainManagerAssembly value="MyDomain"/>
</runtime>
```

And MyDomain.cs:

```
namespace MyDomain
{   
    public class MyDomainManager : AppDomainManager
    {       
        public override void InitializeNewDomain(AppDomainSetup appDomainInfo)
        {
             // Never hit
        }
     }
}
```

I've tried signing the domain assembly, adding the public key token info in the  tag.  Oddly, if I change the assembly name in the app.config to some garbage data, it doesn't throw a TypeLoadException, where as if I change the domain name in the plain WPF application, it does throw an exception.  Are there any other security settings I need to set to make the XBAP load my AppDomainManager?

Comment: In my experience with XBAPs security issues do not cause silent failures.  You could try running it as a full trust application but I suspect the problem may be that the XBAP sandbox is just bypassing your custom app domain manager entirely.

Comment: @RogerN I already had it as a full trust application and still wouldn't load.  I'm able to get it to load the assembly if I do Assembly.Load or instantiate MyDomainManager directly, but at that stage it looks like it's too late for me to do what I need it to do.  We're trying to streamline our configuration settings so our AppDomainManager is copying an updated app.config to a common shared  location and updating the ConfigurationFile proeprty.  After the XBAP is loaded it will not let me change the current app domain's configuration location settings.